# System() no suitable conversion C++

Tags: c++, system

I have 2 lists with file names.

```
std::list<std::string> userfontlist;
std::list<std::string>::iterator it;
std::list<std::string> CAATfontlist;
std::list<std::string>::iterator it2;
std::list<std::string> doesnthavelist;
```

and I want to compare the 2 lists, and delete the value it matches. every seems to be fine until I add the "del /F /Q /A" to the y.c_string().

```
for (it = userfontlist.begin(); it !=userfontlist.end(); ++it){
    for(it2 = CAATfontlist.begin();it2 !=CAATfontlist.end();++it2){
        if(*it==*it2){
            string y = *it;
            string k = y.c_str();
            string a = "del /F /Q /A " + k;
            system(a);

        }
    }
 }
```

system(a) Says I have "no suitable conversion function from std string to const char * exists". If I put the whole thing as 1 string it works, but not when I concatenate the string and the y.c_str(). I have had no luck trying to convert the std::string to const *char, not even sure if that even helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exactly as it says, there's no version of `system()` that understands `std::string` and `std::string` can't be freely converted to `const char *` (which `system()` does understand), because `std::string` may go away in ways that don't make sense in the general case.

you can *explicitly* convert from `std::string` to `const char *` easily, though:  with `std::string::c_str`,  write your last line as

```
system(a.c_str());
```

Be aware that the returned `const char *`'s lifetime is tied to the `string` it came from, once it goes out of scope, the pointer becomes invalid.  This case is a fine time to use it, though, since `system()` won't "hold on" to the pointer past its own return.

Comment: i think i need to step away. thanks a ton. I guess i didn't realize concatenating made it input mismatch again.

Comment: Actually, it has the exact type you've given defined it as `string a = ...` will always be a `std::string`